# Control access via trust policy with oidc

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, openid-connect, identity-management

I have created custom policy for OIDC with gitlab. Below is policy,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:aud": "https://gitlab.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Above working fine but I need to control access from gitlab.

I have tried as below,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:aud": "https://gitlab.com"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:sub": "project_path:<project or group>"
                }

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

as per above policy getting , any idea that we can add here or issue with my side?

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0):

Solutions i have used ,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:aud": "https://gitlab.com",
              "gitlab.com:sub": "project_path:<project or group>"
                }

            }
        }
    ]
}
```